# Тире или запятая в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

*Маша* (**?**) *та всегда знает, что делать.*

Какой знак уместнее поставить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При **именительном темы**, тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется личное или указательное местоимение в качестве слова-отсылки, ставится тире:

> Тягач – он как танк, только без башни (газ.); Марченко – тот был
> человек, золотой человек (Каз.); Дорога в дождь – она не сладость,
> дорога в дождь – она беда (Евт.).

***Маша — та всегда знает, что делать.***

> Примечание. *Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание с
> запятой: Врач, он ведь тоже не Бог (Бык.); Судьбы человеческие, они –
> каждая сама по себе, хотя мы вроде бы сообща и всё у нас должно быть
> общим (Аст.); Наташа, та знала, что за человек ее тетя (Бит.).*

Comment: Считаю, что в предложениях: ‟Тягач – он как танк, только без башни” и ‟Дорога в дождь – она не сладость, дорога в дождь – она беда (Евт.)” — следует ставить тире, но в предложениях: ‟Марченко... тот был человек, золотой человек (Каз.)” и ‟Маша... та всегда знает, что делать” — многоточие намного больше подходит, ведь человек делает эмоциональную паузу задумываясь. Для такого рода паузы многоточие намного больше подходит, чем тире.

Answer (score 1):

Тут непонятно, что человек хочет выразить, так как может быть два смысла:

1. Люди обсуждают двух Маш, и дабы обозначить не ту Машу, которую обсуждают в последних предложениях, используют местоимение ‟та”. Маша та всегда знает, что делать.
2. Также может быть такое предложение: ‟Маша... та всегда знает, что делать. Эта шкура нигде не пропадет”. Считаю, что многоточие намного больше подходит, чем тире, так как конкретно в данном предложении после слова ‟Маша” человек сделает эмоциональную паузу, задумываясь.

Comment: Спасибо! Речь не о двух Машах, а о характеристике одной Маши)

Answer (score 1):

В разговорной речи встречаются конструкции с двойным подлежащим: существительное дублируется местоимением. В таких случаях перед местоимением после существительного обычно ставится тире.

***Жалобщики - они всегда найдутся.***

Ваше предложение:

***Маша - та всегда знает, что делать.***